# Cant exit fullscreen mode for app in OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: osx-mountain-lion

I think I've entered fullscreen with a program called BBEdit. The background turns into the one seen on the screenshot below, and I lose all other windows and, my dock etc. How can I exit this?

[image]

There isn't a close icon I can see anywhere, and <kbd>Esc</kbd> doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

By hovering at the top of the screen I get an icon top right to exit fullscreen mode. There is a bit of a delay before it comes into view though.